# Unique by Most Recent Date

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects that I need to filter, for example:

```json
    [
       {
          "name":"Aaron",
          "status":"Pending",
          "createdDate":"1-1-2000"
       },
       {
          "name":"Bob",
          "status":"Approved",
          "createdDate":"1-2-2000"
       },
       {
          "name":"Aaron",
          "status":"Rejected",
          "createdDate":"1-3-2000"
       }
    ]
```

My intention is to get an array unique by name but only by most recent date, so Aarons's "Pending" object is not included since it was created before the "Rejected" object was created.

```json
    [
       {
          "name":"Bob",
          "status":"Approved",
          "createdDate":"1-2-2000"
       },
       {
          "name":"Aaron",
          "status":"Rejected",
          "createdDate":"1-3-2000"
       }
    ]
```

I have the idea that I can extract all of the objects into their own arrays by name, then grab the latest one from each and add them to a final array, but seems like there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
let map = new Map()
for (let item of list) {
  if (!map.has(item.name)) {
    map.set(item.name, item); // add missing
    continue;
  }
  let current = map.get(item.name);
  if (new Date(item.createdDate) > new Date(current.createdDate)) {
    map.set(item.name, item) // override with a better one
  } 
}
let filteredList = Array.from(map.values())
```